# Launching a popup via in octobercms backend via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

Im trying to figure out how to launch a popup window with a relation widget in the backend using the Ajax framework for Octobercms.

The anchor provides a `data-control='popup'` option for creating a backend popups. The framework uses a jQuery method to call the backend `$.request('onMethodName', { data: {id: id} });`.

I've tried to add additional options for example `$.request('onMethodname', { data: {id: tempMarker.id,control: 'popup' },control: 'popup',dataControl: 'popup' });`

But with no luck. The documentation doesn't say how to do it either. I'm attaching this to a click event for a map marker (img tag) in the backend, a popup should appear to edit the marker data.

Answer (score 1):

This was simple as replacing the `$.request('onSomething')` with `$.popup(handler: 'onSomething')`

Found this thanks to https://octobertricks.com/tricks/update-records-from-list-view-in-a-popup